# NodeJS package outputting empty string

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, chalk

I'm trying to create my own NodeJS package that uses the [chalk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk)  to output colored strings, but i'm getting empty string as output( when i run `node test.js` in terminal ) I tried searching online but couldn't find any reason for this. Does anyone have an idea what could be causing this error?

**index.js file**

```
import chalk from 'chalk';
import pkg from 'koa/lib/request';
const { charset } = pkg;
const fontColors = ['red','green','yellow','blue','magenta','cyan',];
export const colourfulLog = (string) => {
    const colorString = string.split(' ')
        .map(word => {
            const randclrindex = Math.floor(Math.random() * fontColors.length);
            const randColor = fontColors[randclrindex];
            return chalk[randColor][word];
        })
        .join(' ');
    console.log(colorString);
}
```

**test.js file**

```
import { colourfulLog } from './index.js';
colourfulLog(' Test the colorful log package');
```

**package.json file**

```
{
  "name": "colorful-log-ax",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "first package",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },

  "author": "AT",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "chalk": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "type": "module"
  
}
```

Comment: The colors in Chalk are a function so `chalk[randColor][word]` needs to be `chalk[randColor](word)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in your index.js file:

```
    return chalk[randColor][word];
```

You are using square brackets to dynamically specify a method: chalk[randColor] is like saying chalk.randColor, then you have to apply it to `word` like this:

```
    return chalk[randColor](word);
```